# Nuances of meaning between "nicht nur ... sondern" and "nicht nur ... sondern auch"

Tags: meaning

> **nicht nur** Felix, **sondern** jeder einzelne Einwohner
>
> {compared to}: **nicht nur** Felix, **sondern auch** jeder einzelne Einwohner

How do these two similar constructions have different meanings? I wonder if the first construction places emphasis on "jeder einzelne Einwohner" whereas in the second the focus is equally on "Felix" and "jeder einzelne Einwohner"?

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/11511/what-does-nein-mean-in-this-context

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a difference in meaning.

> nicht nur Felix, sondern jeder einzelne Einwohner

This suggests Felix to be one of the inhabitants.

It means: Not only (inhabitant) Felix, but each and every inhabitant ...

> nicht nur Felix, sondern auch jeder einzelne Einwohner

This implicates, that Felix is not among the inhabitants. He may be a guest of the village.

It means: Felix and also each and every inhabitant ...

Comment: In such a conversation, I think both of the options could be used. i.e If I say; *Felix muss die Betriebkosten zahlen*, which options mentioned above would you use?

Comment: @AdInfinitum: _»Felix muss die Betriebskosten zahlen«_ means that Felix is the only payer. If we say _»Felix muss Betriebskosten zahlen«_ there may be other payers as well.

Comment: What is the difference between; »nicht nur Felix, sondern jeder einzelne Einwohner muss die Betriebkosten zahlen« with »nicht nur Felix, sondern auch jeder einzelne Einwohner« ? Who pays the Betriebkosten in these two examples?

Comment: @AdInfinitum: The difference is: Felix 1 has another place of residence than Felix 2.

Comment: »Nicht nur Bayern München, sondern jede einzelne Mannschaften in Bundesliga kann den Pokal gewinnen« is wrong then? (I am asking to learn btw :)

Comment: @AdInfinitum: _»Nicht nur Bayern München, sondern jede einzelne Mannschaft der Bundesliga kann den Pokal gewinnen«_ is correct; _»sondern auch«_ would be incorrect, since Bayern München is part of the Bundesliga.